# How to publish website on internet so that only referred people can access it

Tags: html, facebook, web

This question might be for web developers here.

**Is there an out-of-shelf solution available to publish website on internet to a very small audience.**

I want to publish my website to small number of people, maybe to some of my friends and their friends who are in different parts of world. And, they can refer max 10 people.
I would like referral to work **through facebook** and email.

I want to release it to less people in beginning and once I have ironed out scale and performance issues - if there are any, then I would like to release to general public.

**Question Specifics:**
How to release a website to limited or referred users only. i.e. only referred people could log it in (using their email or facebook) and use it. Is there any out-of-shelf solution available (I am ready to pay for it)

Comment: What software are you using? Any specific programming languages? Or does it matter?

Comment: Even if there is not an off-the-shelf solution available you could hire a freelancer to do it for you.

Comment: @IanHunter, it is mostly CSS/HTML/JS and relies on webservices to get data.. I am concerned that web-services will be hit bad if uncontrollable number of people use it.

Comment: @BenedictLewis, thanks! do you have any recommendation from where to hire a good freelancer to do this job? I am asking because I don't have any experience in doing such work.

Comment: @Watt Have a look at [Freelancer](http://www.Freelancer.com). There is a large selection of good developers who can do projects starting at about $30.

Answer (score 2):

I would use basic authentication (for Apache: http://www.apacheweek.com/features/userauth, for IIS: http://www.authenticationtutorial.com/tutorial/basic.htm)

That way, you leave the authentication mechanism to the browser/server, so you are sure not to leave any security hole wide open.

If you don't have access to the server configuration, then you need a **server-side** authentication page (JavaScript will be useless here, security-wise) which will create a session token once you enter the right credentials, and then on every webpage you have, you need to check for that session token before displaying anything.

If you only have HTML and JS at your disposal, then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply creating a login feature for the account, and YOU as the admin, have to approve each new user.  That way, You have total control over allowing people to use you site.  A simple google search will show you many ways to do this with php and a database.